# Upload Images to Mkt Cloud Content Builder using a form in a Landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, images, form, fileupload

I'm using a form on a Mkt Cloud landing page that uploads images to the content builder.

To give you context, when the client uploads an image, we are storing other variables that are input in the form, like the email and the name, and we concatenate the name of the file that is uploaded to save the image name in a DE, like this: 'Selfie_nameFile_Subscriber_xxxxxxx'

We are able to upload the images and the other variables to the DE, but, in some cases, we get a new record in the DE, filled with the data inputed in the form, but the image name is not stored in the DE and the image is not uploaded to the content builder.

I had some problems with the size of the images uploaded because the content builder only allows images no larger than 5 MB, but I'm using a script that compresses the image before uploading it, so I'm uploading images no larger than 14 MB, and in my test runs, I can upload them and get all the fields correctly filled in the DE, including the name of the image, but we've had this running for a week now, and some clients do not have their picture uploaded even though there is a record for them in the DE with the field for the image name empty.

Anyone who has tried something similar? and got this working fine?

Comment: are you capturing the response from the API call? Just an FYI those are publically accessible files

Comment: Well, I've created an API in the marketing set up, put the credencials in a js. file and i'm calling this file in the landing page that contains the form.

Answer (score 0):

What is the full image name when the DE row is saved but image in CB is not? If it contains special characters, it might break the upload to CB. I assume you sometimes don't get the image name in the DE because you use the one from the API call response, not the one that you post in the request. You could try logging the latter and look for special characters.

As @EazyE mentioned, it's best to store the API response somewhere so that it's possible to see the error message.

I've also developed such form page and one mistake I've made was to post both uncompressed image from the form field and base64 string of a compressed image. I was uploading those to a separate code resource and it prevented the script from triggering altogether, it did not even trigger try-catch logging. I assume the payload size was too big, because once I removed the unnecessary 'weight' it worked fine.

Comment: ''What is the full image name when the DE row is saved but image in CB is not? ''
None. For example, if I have two different situations, I have one record in the DE that has the name of the image empty but the image is in the CB. I know that because I have this template name for the image 'Selfie_nameFile_Subs_xxxx',  and I can see their subskey.  And have another case where the name of the image is empty in the DE and there is no image in the CB for this subscriber. I have tried uploading an image with a special character, and for me, works. I cannot replicate this issue. :/